# HTTP thingsboard issue

Tags: http, alarm, thingsboard

i tried to send data to simulate some alarms in thingsboard  ,when i send data over MQTT it works but when i send data with http ,alarm dont show up in thingsboard , probably it's an issue of keeping connexion with the device, i tried to pass **-H "connection :close"** but i have the same issue.
i tested that with two different  versions  tb 3.3.3 and  tb 3.4.
and when this happens with http and i tried to change to mqtt , still bugged .to resolve that i need to create another device profile and i start sending with MQTT to see the alarms

my http request is like that  :

```
 `import requests,json

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Connetion': 'close',
    'X-Authorization': 'Bearer MY JWT TOKEN',
}

params = {
    'scope': 'ANY',
}

json_data = {
    'temperature': 90,
}

response = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/deviceID/timeseries/ANY',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
)`
```

i create the alarm using device profile because i dont know how to create a rule chain and call 7 or 6 shared attribute  with from different devices

Comment: I tried with rule chain i still see the alarm when i send over mqtt but over Http still the same dilemma , i receive data but alarm dnt show up

Comment: Maybe your device profile is configured only for `MQTT` transport?

Comment: nope i choose default when i receive http requests.... the thing is i receive data but alarm dnt show up when i use http